# Anyone know why my on-click isn't firing in this core-collapse component test?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I've tried to get my div to click a few different ways and it just doesn't seem to fire for some reason.. I may be a bit tired. I've literally just copied from the documentation and it won't work.

```
<div onclick="{{toggle}}">toggle collapse</div>

<core-collapse id="collapse">
    test test test test
</core-collapse>
```

and the js

```
var collapseBlock = document.shadowRoot.querySelector('#collapse');

toggle: function testName () {
    collapseBlock.toggle();
}
```

I think it's an issue with my expression? I have polymer.html imported and core-collapse imported as well. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Bonus: if someone could explain how exactly the {{toggle}} knows to look at the function I have there that would be fantastic. Is it the label 'toggle'? This is actually probably the issue.. Haven't been able to really understand how exactly it *binds* to the js I have there from the dom.

edit: changed on-click to onclick, still not working

Comment: Replace `on-click` with `onclick` instead

Comment: yup tried that, still not firing :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a more-complete example, showing you how to bind a click event to a function in a polymer-element.

```
<polymer-element name="x-collapse">
<template>
  <div on-click="{{ toggle }}">toggle collapse</div>
  <core-collapse id="collapse">
    foo
  </core-collapse>
</template>
<script>
Polymer('x-collapse', {
  toggle: function() {
    this.$.collapse.toggle();
  }
});
</script>
</polymer-element>

<x-collapse></x-collapse>
```

Comment: This is a very clear example, so thank you! I actually was able to find my issue from looking how you formatted the js here -- I was nesting the 'toggle' label in the same function as the 'ready' label. whoopsies. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div onclick="testName();">Toggle collapse</div>


function testName(){
        collapseBlock.toggle();
}
```

Comment: didn't work, thanks for the suggestion though! I'm pretty sure my issue is with how polymer uses double mustache expressions..

Comment: If you can post your entire code it will be easier to help you